# Disable gnome-calendar

Tags: 19.10, evolution, calendar, gnome-calendar

When my system restores from hibernation, about 50% of the time I get a crash next boot that tells me the Calendar was the problem.

However, when I open "Calendar," I don't see an option to disable this application.

How can I disable/stop/delete the buggy process for good?

## Update

Feedback from question asked in comments:

```
$ ls -al /var/crash
total 34012
drwxrwsrwt 2 root whoopsie 4096 Mar 19 08:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root 4096 Apr 18 2019 ..
-rw-r----- 1 usern whoopsie 15667441 Mar 19 08:20 _usr_bin_gnome-calendar.1000.crash
-rw-r--r-- 1 usern whoopsie 0 Mar 19 08:20 _usr_bin_gnome-calendar.1000.upload
-rw------- 1 whoopsie whoopsie 37 Mar 19 08:20 _usr_bin_gnome-calendar.1000.uploaded
```

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`.